# jQuery ajax isn't sending post variable to WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Im trying to take form data and send it to WordPress with an ajax call.
The call goes through, but the variable does not reach the PHP script.
Why is that?

I have checked, that formData holds a variable.

This is my js:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( 'form' ).submit( function( event ) {
        var formData = {'title': $('input[name=title]').val() };
        $.ajax( {
            url: '<?php echo  admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
            data: {
                action : 'my_ajax_action',
                data : formData,
            },
            success:function( data ) {
                console.log( data );
            },
            error: function( errorThrown ) {
                console.log( errorThrown );
            },
        } );
    event.preventDefault();
    } );
});
```

This is my PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax_action', 'my_ajax_action_callback' );

function my_ajax_action_callback() {
    $title =isset( $_POST['data'] ) ? $_POST['data'] : 'N/A';
    echo $title;
    die();
}
```

Comment: you will have to use `wp_create_nonce` to get your js data back to php. When the nonce is created inside php you will have to set it inside your `data:{}` in your JS. Sorry for the short answer but I'm on the move. Anyway look up `wp_create_nonce` its pretty straight forward

Answer (score 2):

The default jQuery ajax method is GET, so maybe that's your issue?  Try adding method: 'POST' to your options:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  ... etc
```

Comment: adding method: 'POST',

Comment: Adding method: 'POST' doesn't change anything. I still get nothing back.